# Is it possible to get id of a new session in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, ruby-on-rails-4

In my controllers i can use `session.id` to get the current visitor's session id, but if it's a new visitor (or with cleared cookies) without a session rails will generate a new session for him and send with the response. But `session.id` in this case returns `nil` so you only can get that id on the next request. Is it somehow possible to get it in the same request, when a new session is generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the id is generated really late in the Rails request response cycle. As far as I understand, it's [generated (randomly) in rack](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb#L234), which is called from [here](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb#L325).

Possibly, you could override this method and let it return something you generated (make sure you get your crypto right) earlier in the request response cycle.

Comment: So, seems there is no clean solution. Fortunately, it's not very important in my situation and it would be better just not to use that id when it's nil. Thanks for the info!